# PHP Warning: Cannot load module "http" because required module "raphf" is not loaded in Unknown on line 0

Tags: apt, php, laravel

When entering artisan commands in laravel- ubuntu 20.04 it shows following error

PHP Warning: Cannot load module "http" because required module "raphf" is not loaded in Unknown on line 0

PHP version 8.1.1, Laravel 8 , Ubuntu 20.04

[screen shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cs9gm.png)

Comment: Try `sudo apt install php-raphf`.

Comment: E: Unable to locate package php-raph

Comment: It's in the `universe` repo.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I enable the "Universe" repository?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/148638/how-do-i-enable-the-universe-repository)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Installing the package solved the issue for me:

```
$ sudo apt install php-raphf
```

Comment: php-raphf is already the newest version (2.0.1+1.1.2-13+ubuntu20.04.1+deb.sury.org+10).

Comment: @ahmednawazbutt Try to install with specific your php version. For example, if you use php8.1, try `sudo apt install php8.1-raphf`. To check your php version, you can run command, `php --version`.

Answer (score 3):

Some more details. This occurs when you switch PHP versions - it happened to me when I switched to PHP 8.

If you check for your installed version of php-raphf with

```
apt list php-raphf
```

You will notice that you (most likely) have it. However, if you run

```
$ sudo apt install php-raphf
```

as described above, Ubuntu will install a PHP-dependent version:

```
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  php-raphf php8.1-raphf
```

Comment: Yes  If you have multiple php versions installed, like when using php-fpm, you'll have to specify the version number. Usually you can check in '''/etc/php''' or '''/use/bin/''' wich php versions you have installed and you can switch with '''sudo update-alternatives'''' for php-cli and separately in your webserver config (nginx, Apache, etc)